# jquery image mouseover and picture library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, picture-library

I would like to use images in a picture library to have images with mouseovers.
but i would need two images one on mouseout and the other in mouseover.
Looking at different solutions is where will i store the second image wince i can only have one image uploaded per item.
Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picture Libraries actually store two thumbnails for you. The thumbnails are stored in _t and _w folders in the Picture Library, and the naming conventions are easy to follow.

The sizes may not be exactly what you want, but between the versions, you may be able to scale them to your needs on the fly.

Comment: Thanks Guys.If they are stored in _t and _w folders which i believe it is automatically generated how does that help me.
What i really need is to be able to have 2 images in an item and then i can easily swap images onmousover and onmouseout.
Cheers

Comment: Well, you can use those smaller thumbnails if they serve your purpose. If you need to separate images that aren't the same, then save them using some naming convention that makes sense, like image_start and image_mouseover.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom webservice which either generates the other images on the fly and have jQuery query that - or you generate the images with an event handler on image update/created in the image library into another library and jQuery can get the images from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another list/library which will hold the second image based on the id of the List Item in the first list. Then you can query that list based on the id and fetch the image on the fly.
But the best approach will always be to create a new picture column in the original list and have 2 images associated with one list item. But from your post it seems that you cannot do that.

Also, the following post might come in handy if you are dealing with Picture Libraries:
http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Tanmay/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=22